# Объясните ,пожалуйста, что делает этот цикл?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

````
# scraper.py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
quotes = soup.find_all('span', class_='text')
authors = soup.find_all('small', class_='author')
tags = soup.find_all('div', class_='tags')

for i in range(0, len(quotes)):
    print(quotes[i].text)
    print('--' + authors[i].text)
    tagsforquote = tags[i].find_all('a', class_='tag')
    for tagforquote in tagsforquote:
        print(tagforquote.text)
    print('\n')```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Перебирает цитаты.

Answer (score 0):

С сайта, указанного в `url` берётся список цитат.

Странитца загружается в `response` и парсится через `BeautifulSoup`

При этом цитаты попадают в `quotes`, их авторы в `authors`, а теги в переменную `tags`

Далее в цикле через `print` выводятся все спаршенные цитаты, авторы этих цитат и теги, извлечённые из ссылок с тегами.

Comment: Спасибо большое!Почему тогда у нас цикл от 0 и до len(quotes)

Comment: Метод find_all заносит результаты в массив от нуля до крайнего элемента. В цикле они обходятся и выводятся в зависимости от количества извлечённых цитат, которое устанавливается через len (длинна массива)